# Selenium doesn't display IE when run via Task Schedular

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, nunit, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

It's not a problem and actually is a nice side affect, but it is confusing me.

When I run the test suite via the command line I see IE pop up and the test run.

When I run it with the exact same arguments from the Task Schedular though it doesn't display IE.  The test seems to run correctly (I'm getting the expected `TestResults.xml` so it all looks OK.

Why's this happening though?

The command is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "Path_to_test_assembly"
```

P.S.  I'm using the .NET version of Selenium with the IE web driver.

Comment: Where are you running these test, on some remote machine? Is it windows machine?

Comment: @acikojevic Yes, Windows (2012 Server) and everything's local to the machine.

Comment: Ok, when you run it using scheduler, are you logged on that machine? Do you physically see your screen where you expect your tests to run?

Comment: @acikojevic Yup, I'm remoting into it, see the desktop etc.  When I run via the command line i see IE doing things.

Comment: How are you remoting into it?

Comment: @acikojevic Remote Desktop.

Comment: I think this is because it's running as a service on a windows machine. In later versions of Windows, services run so that they are seperate from the interactive desktop . Therefore you can still perform any actions you want on your desktop whilst the service runs hidden from the user's view. I had the same thing happen when running Selenium tests via TeamCity build agents

Comment: @Corporalis That sounds reasonable.

Comment: In theory if you were to run the task under the account you login as, you should see the tests run. Having said that I've not run tests from a task scheduler before

Comment: @Corporalis I tried exactly that, running the test under my cerds.

Comment: Ahhh looks like it may be part of the security design of the task scheduler: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4567285/4045532. With a team city build agent it was running as a service, so it worked when we updated the user account.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, it seems that the problem is with your access to remote machine. Your IE test are running as a background process on that machine, or running on wrong sessionID. It means that there could be more users/accounts, and your test is running on wrong one.
I'm not sure how exactly are you running this, but you could check your session ID's by typing `qwinsta` in command line on that machine.

If you want it to run properly you should pass this sessionID as a parameter when connecting to remote desktop, for example, if using psexec and your sessionID is 2 than you pass "-i 2" when starting it. It means that it will interact on user with sessionID 2 on that machine.

Comment: It's just a plain, vanilla Remote Desktop connection.  Everything is local to the machine apart from my keyboard and me.

Comment: Ok, you did not provide enough info in your question so I was on the wrong track. And I must say that it's pretty lame to downvote someone who took his time to help. :/